# Conditional arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do I pass arguments when launching bash script so that specific lines are executed within the script

For example (`createfile.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

export CLIENT1_DIR="<path1>"
export CLIENT2_DIR="<path2>"
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j client1.json
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j client2.json
```

Then

```
$ ./createfile.sh client1
```

should only execute `client1` specific lines, and replacing it with `client2` should execute only `client2` specific lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many solutions to this.  Here's one:

```
#!/bin/bash

client="$1"

case "$client" in
    "client1") export CLIENT1_DIR="<path1>" ;;
    "client2") export CLIENT2_DIR="<path2>" ;;
    *)  printf 'Invalid client argument: %s\n' "$client" >&2
        exit 1 ;;
esac

chef-solo -c solo.rb -j "$client".json
```

The `client` variable gets the value of the first command line argument.

The `case` statement sets either `CLIENT1_DIR` or `CLIENT2_DIR` depending on this value (or exits with an error message if an invalid value was used).

Then `chef-solo` is invoked with the JSON file corresponding to what was given on the command line.

Answer (score 4):

You have the lines in a function:

```
#!/bin/bash
clientOne(){
    ## client1 specific lines
    echo "one"
}
clientTwo(){
    ## client2 specific lines
    echo "two"
}

case "$1" in
    "client1")
        clientOne
        ;;
    "client2")
        clientTwo
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Wrong option" >&2
        ;;
esac

## Common lines
echo foo
```